# Differences between@property (nonatomic) double longitude &@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I set Entity *longitude* as double and create NSManagedObject Subclass. In properties.h I got the longitude as

```
 @property (nonatomic) double longitude;
```

Then a error jumps out as

> Assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'NSNumber *'

in below line

```
photo.longitude=@([photoDictionary[FLICKR_LONGITUDE] doubleValue]);
```

Things didn't get well until I change the code into

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
```

I`m confused about these.

Any advice would be appreciative.

Comment: You need to say what error jumped out, what changes you made, and what the new error is. You also need to show your code, in particular declarations of any variables and the lines which cause errors. Edit your question to add this information and people might be able to help you.

Comment: @CRD Thanks for your advice.I have made some change.It`s that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber):

> NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar
>   (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting
>   and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int,
>   long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL.

I.e. `NSNumber` is a class that encapsulates a primitive value (such as a `double` in your case) and provides an object oriented interface (among other things).

What you are trying to do is to assign an object of type `NSNumber` to a property of type `double` (hence the error you are shown).

However, with this code...

```
photo.longitude=@([photoDictionary[FLICKR_LONGITUDE] doubleValue]);
```

... you obtain a `double` from `photoDictionary` by calling `doubleValue` on the `NSNumber` returned and then you re-wrap it in an `NSNumber` using the `NSNumber` literal: `@(...)`. If you remoVe the literal and simply assign `[photoDictionary[FLICKR_LONGITUDE] doubleValue]` directly to `photo.longitude` you should be fine.

Comment: Note that `photoDictionary[FLICKR_LONGITUDE]` need not be an `NSNumber`, just an instance of any class with a `doubleValue` method. Indeed it being an `NSString` would make more sense in this case.

Comment: That`s awesome. Solving my problem perfectly.

Comment: @CRD Really appreciate your notes.